# NGRX 8 reducer returning Object instead of Array

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, angular8, state-management

The data returned from  the reducer is an object but I need it to be an Array.
I've tried returning action.recentSearches but it doesnt not seem to work.

The data that is being returned is:

```
{ "loading": false, "recentSearches": [ { "corpId": "123", "site": "location", "building": "location", "floor": "2N" }, { "corpId": "123", "site": "location", "building": "location", "floor": "09" }, { "corpId": "123", "site": "location", "building": "location", "floor": "01" } ] }`
```

Action:

```
  export const getRecentSearches = createAction(
'[ConfRoom API] Request Recent Searches'
);

export const getRecentSearchesloadSuccess = createAction('[ConfRoom API] Recent Searches Load Success', props<{recentSearches: RecentSearchesModel[]}>());
```

The redcuer:
The console.log does print the values i need but returning action.recentSearches does not work

```
export const initialState = [];
const _confRoomReducer = createReducer(
initialState,
on(confRoomActionTypes.getRecentSearches,  state=> ({      
  ...state
})),
on(confRoomActionTypes.getRecentSearchesloadSuccess,(state, { recentSearches }) => ({ ...state, recentSearches })) )

  export function confRoomReducer(state, action) {
  console.log(action.recentSearches);
return _confRoomReducer(state, action);
```

Value in component

```
recentSearches$: Observable<RecentSearchesModel[]> = this.store.select(state => state.recentSearches);
```

**Update:**

Have made 2 edits to the reducer:

```
export const state = [];
export const initialState = [];


const _confRoomReducer = createReducer(
initialState,
on(confRoomActionTypes.getRecentSearches,  state=>     
 state
),
on(confRoomActionTypes.getRecentSearchesloadSuccess,(state,  {recentSearches} ) => ([ ...state, recentSearches ])) )

 export function confRoomReducer(state, action) {
return _confRoomReducer(state, action);
```

Data is now being return like so but I need to get rid of the outer [] I'm wrapping the data response with in [ ], some point in the reducer but this is the closest I've gotten to it functioning correctly:

```
    [ [ { "corpId": "123", "site": "location", "building": "location, "floor": "01,02" }, { "corpId": "123", "site": "location", "building": "location", "floor": "01,02" } ] ]
```

The data can be read by my ngFor but it is not working as expected as it requires me to add the index for data to be displayed:

```
 <tr *ngFor="let recentSearch of recentSearches$ | async; let i = index" ng-class-odd="'striped'">
  <td>{{recentSearch[0]}}, {{recentSearch[0].building}}, {{recentSearch[0].floor}}</td>
</tr>
```

**Update**
By adding the the recommended changes to the reducer I was able to come up with solution but I'm not sure is it the correct way to access the data I need

**Reducer**

```
export interface RecentSearchesModel {
site: string;
corpId: string;
building: string;
floor: string
}

export interface State {
  resultList: RecentSearchesModel[];
}

const initialState: State = {
resultList: []
};


const _confRoomReducer = createReducer(
initialState,
on(confRoomActionTypes.getRecentSearches, state => ({
...state
})),
on(
confRoomActionTypes.getRecentSearchesloadSuccess,
(state, { recentSearches }) => ({ ...state, resultList: recentSearches })
  )
);

export function confRoomReducer(state, action) {
  return _confRoomReducer(state, action);
}
```

**Data**
Now the data is returned like so

```
{ "resultList": [ { "corpId": "123", "site": "CHINA", "building": "BUILDING 12", "floor": "2N" }, { "corpId": "123", "site": "US", "building": "BIG BUILDING", "floor": "09" }, { "corpId": "123", "site": "LONDON", "building": "BIG BEN", "floor": "01" } ] }
```

But to access the data I want in my component, I had to edit the model and add resultList[]

```
export interface RecentSearchesModel {
  corpId: string;
  site: string;
  building: string;
  floor: string;
resultList[];
}
```

I feel like I shouldnt have to add resultList to my model as data is never really mapped to it, I'm just using it to access the label the data is associated with 
**Component**

```
recentSearches$: Observable<RecentSearchesModel[]> = this.store.select(state => state.recentSearches.resultList);
```

Comment: try [...state] instead of {...state}

Comment: are you using entity adapter? Please include your State interface and initialState in your sample above

Comment: Hi I have updated to show the full reducer file, I am new to ngrx so I could be implementing these incorrecly

Comment: Hi, I've made the recommended changes and have come up with a solution for my problem, I've made an update to my question to reflect that, I'd really appreciate your opinion on it @JamesD

Comment: As you'll see in the example app link I've given you'll see at the bottom how to make a selector, you're exporting a function but you should pass your data through selectors. I suggest you clone that example app and just run through it. If you follow that you'll find how to properly implement ngrx with the newest version. All selectors are build in a main reducer file ref. https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/projects/example-app/src/app/books/reducers/index.ts and it's these selectors you'll specifically call to get the slice of state you need, in your case the resultList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the [example app](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/projects/example-app/src/app/books/reducers/books.reducer.ts) given by the ngrx team.

**If you're trying to store data given to you by the frontend you're initializing wrong**

You should have an interface for you confroom list

```js
// have a model file:
export interface ConfRoom{
    corpId: number;
    site: string;
    location: string;
    floor: string;
}

// in your reducer
export interface State {
  confList: ConfRoom[];
}
const initialState: State = {
  confList: []
};


const _confRoomReducer = createReducer(
initialState,
// this line does nothing and can be delete...
// on(confRoomActionTypes.getRecentSearches,  state=>     
//  state
// ),
// if recentSearches should change confList do this
on(confRoomActionTypes.getRecentSearchesloadSuccess,(state,  {recentSearches} ) => ( {...state, confList: recentSearches})) )

// if recentSearches should be added to confList do this
on(confRoomActionTypes.getRecentSearchesloadSuccess,(state,  {recentSearches} ) => ( {...state, confList: [...confList, recentSearches]})) )
```

**If you're trying to get backend data:**
Here's an example when using api calls and filling data.

this is a simple reducer with just a load:

```
import { createEntityAdapter, EntityAdapter, EntityState } from '@ngrx/entity';
import { createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';

import {
  ProjectCollectionApiActions,
  ProjectCollectionActions
} from '../../actions';
import { Project } from 'src/app/core/models';

export interface State extends EntityState<Project> {
  loading: boolean;
  loaded: boolean;
}

export const adapter: EntityAdapter<Project> = createEntityAdapter<Project>({
  selectId: (project: Project) => project.id,
  sortComparer: false,

});

export const initialState: State = adapter.getInitialState({
  loading: false,
  loaded: false
});

export const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(ProjectCollectionActions.loadProjectCollection, (state) => ({
    ...state,
    loading: true,
  })),
  on(ProjectCollectionApiActions.loadProjectsSuccess,
    (state, { projects }) => adapter.addMany(projects, {
      ...state,
      loading: false,
      loaded: true
    })
  ),
);

export const getLoaded = (state: State) => state.loaded;

export const getLoading = (state: State) => state.loading;
```

I import that in a main file called index.ts

```js
import {
  createSelector,
  createFeatureSelector,
  combineReducers,
  Action,
} from '@ngrx/store';

import * as fromDates from './reports/dates.reducer';
import * as fromSuperIntendents from './superintendents/superintendent.reducer';
import * as fromReports from './reports/reports.reducer';
import * as fromProjects from './projects/projects.reducer';
import * as fromMachines from './machines/machines.reducer';

import * as fromLaborers from './laborers/laborers.reducer';
import * as fromCollection from './reports/collection.reducer';
import * as fromRoot from '../../../state/reducers';
import { generateMockReport, Report } from 'src/app/reports/models';

export interface DataState {
  dates: fromDates.State;
  superintendents: fromSuperIntendents.State;
  reports: fromReports.State;
  laborers: fromLaborers.State;
  collection: fromCollection.State;
  projects: fromProjects.State;
  machines: fromMachines.State;
}

export interface State extends fromRoot.State {
  data: DataState;
}

export function reducers(state: DataState | undefined, action: Action) {
  return combineReducers({
    dates: fromDates.reducer,
    superintendents: fromSuperIntendents.reducer,
    reports: fromReports.reducer,
    laborers: fromLaborers.reducer,
    collection: fromCollection.reducer,
    projects: fromProjects.reducer,
    machines: fromMachines.reducer
  })(state, action);
}



export const getDataState = createFeatureSelector<State, DataState>('data');

//here all my other reducers come
//...
//

export const getProjectsState = createSelector(
  getDataState,
  (state: DataState) => state.projects
);
export const {
  selectIds: getProjectIds,
  selectEntities: getProjectEntities,
  selectAll: getAllProjects,
  selectTotal: getTotalProjects,
} = fromProjects.adapter.getSelectors(getProjectsState); 

export const getProjectsLoaded = createSelector(
  getProjectsState,
  fromProjects.getLoaded
);

export const getLoadedProjectIds = createSelector(
  getProjectIds,
  (ids) => { return ids as string[] }
)

export const getLoadedProjects = createSelector(
  getProjectEntities,
  getLoadedProjectIds,
  (entities, ids) => {
      return ids
          .map(id => entities[id])
  }
);
```

**This gives me a result like this:** [image]

Reference to effects page:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Actions, createEffect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import {
  ProjectCollectionApiActions,
  ProjectCollectionActions
} from '../../actions';

import { Project } from 'src/app/core/models';
import { LoggingService } from 'src/app/core/services/logging.service';
import { Update } from '@ngrx/entity';
import { ProjectService } from 'src/app/core/services/project.service';

@Injectable()
export class ProjectCollectionEffects {

  loadProjectCollection$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(ProjectCollectionActions.loadProjectCollection),
      switchMap(() => {
        return this.projectService.getList().pipe(
          map((projects: Project[]) =>
          ProjectCollectionApiActions.loadProjectsSuccess({ projects })
          ),
          catchError(error => {
            this.logging.log('Error in loadCollection effect"',"Project load collection effect - within Approvals")
            return of(ProjectCollectionApiActions.loadProjectsFailure({ error: {...error} }))
          })
        )
      })
    )
  );  


  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private projectService: ProjectService,
    private logging: LoggingService
  ) {}
}
```

**EDIT**
If you have no Id, you could just fake one by adding one to the data in the service:

```js
let counter = 0; 
return this.http.get<ConfRoom[]>(${url},httpOptions).pipe( 
    map((data: any) => { 
        let result: confRoom[] = []; 
        if(Array.isArray(data)){ 
            data.forEach(room=> { 
               result.push({...room, id: counter}); 
               counter = counter +1; 
            }); 
        } 
        return result; 
    }),
   catchError(handleError)
)
```

Though it sound like you just need something like the first part I showed, where i mention you're initializing wrong? (first block of code)

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, only getting back to this now, I do do not have a unique identifier in the data returned..... How can the entityAdapter be edited to handle this situation?

Comment: you could add a fake id to it in the service by mapping the data to an interface that does have a unique id. See edit above

Comment: But it sounds like you just need the first block of code i gave you

Answer (score 0):

You are returning as object, but it's initial state is []
Change like below

```
 on(confRoomActionTypes.getRecentSearches,  state=> state)
```

Comment: Sorry I misinterpreted your response, yes that has got me very close to what I need I will add an update to the question